# Neat expresion for an anti-symmetric matrix

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra

Fix a column vector $\pmb{v}$ and consider the cross product $\pmb{v}^T\times\pmb{x}^T$ for any column vector $\pmb{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3$. One can write
$$\pmb{v}^T\times\pmb{x}^T=A(\pmb{v})\pmb{x}$$
for some matrix $A(\pmb{v})$ as a function of entries from $\pmb{v}$.

**Example:** If $B(\pmb{v})$ is some reflection matrix in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then it is possible to express it in the form
$$B(\pmb{v})=I-\pmb{v}\pmb{v}^T.\tag1$$

> **QUESTION.** Is it possible to write the skew-symmetric matrix $A(\pmb{v})$ as "nice" or "neat" expression in terms of $\pmb{v}$?

Comment: in the quadratic form $x^T Ax$ only the symmetric part of $A$ contributes, the quadratic form is identically zero if $A$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: I think I need to frame the question differently.

Comment: something like $A_{ij}=\sum_k \epsilon_{ijk}v_k$, with $\epsilon_{ijk}$ the [Levi-Civita tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) ?

Comment: There’s provably no $w=(a,b,c)^T$ such that $A(v)=v w^T - w v^T$ (this always annihilates $v \times w$ but $A(v)(v \times w) = v \times (v \times w)$ isn’t necessarily zero)